# Чем нарисовать дерево

Tags: php, javascript

Какую библиотеку использовать для отрисовки иерархической структуры типа дерево?

Вот типа такого:

[image]

Comment: Дерево можно оочень по разному рисовать... Нарисуйте что хотите видеть

Comment: Должны быть соединения.

Comment: Теперь вопрос хороший) Лучше искать рисование графов)

Comment: Вообще я могу через дивы, например, узлы сделать, но вот как стрелки рисовать не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не оно - [Visualization: Organizational Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html)?

Comment: Да, вроде подходит!

Answer (score 0):

[JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/) подойдёт?

Comment: Не такое. Уточню -- нужно чтобы узлы дерева были большие и прямоугольные блоки.

Answer (score 0):

Если допустим вызов внешних утилит, то [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: Норм, но не тащить внешние утилиты не стоит.